# top margin does not work

Tags: html, css

Sorry, i am novice in CSS. I have the following html:

```
<div class="box-A" >Box A is here</div>
 <div class="box-B" >Box B is here</div>
```

and i have tried to apply the following css to it:

```
.box-A{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 13px solid green;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.box-B{
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 40px;
    margin-top: 140 px;
}
```

It works correctly for `box-A` meanwhile when i apply `margin-top: 140 px;` to `box-B` I expect to see a margin around `180px` between 2 boxes.
But nothing happens. Can you please tell me why `margin-top` does not effect?

Comment: you have an error 140 px, the value is 140px (not space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use space between px and number.

```
.box-B{
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 40px;
    margin-top: 140px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding to [w3 schools css margin-top property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin-top.asp) it can happen, that only the biggest of both values (top and bottom) is accepted.

> Margin Collapse. Top and bottom margins of elements are sometimes collapsed into a single margin that is equal to the largest of the two margins.
>   This does not happen on horizontal margins (left and right)! Only vertical margins (top and bottom)!